# One PC with many virtual machines and wireless input/output

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, multiseat

Is it possible to have a powerful PC (or a workstation maybe) with two (or more) virtual machines running on it? For each virtual machine, dedicated mouse/keyboard/monitor(s)/audio may exist connected wirelessly – all this without thin clients.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/151871/is-it-possible-to-run-several-virtual-machines-each-with-independent-mousekeyboa) partially answers the question, but does not cover the wireless part.

Moreover, if I choose a multiseat solution, what's the difference? Is it possible to have virtual machines in multiseat or are the users working on the same Windows installation?

By the way, for a multiseat solution [these](http://softxpand.londonweb.net/) guys are doing the wireless thing, but I cant figure out how. Anyone please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this with a wireless keyboard and mouse:
[Multi-User-PC](http://www.elecomsystems.com/showpages.asp?pid=1006)
And this
[wireless monitor](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-PC-to-Computer-Monitor-HDTV-Wireless-adapter-p-17797.html)